# C# Label List not being released from memory

Tags: c#

Im trying to finish up a Level Editor via a WinForms application and need to create a list of Labels for displaying enemies.

But I noticed my label list is not being released or at least it doesn't seem like it based off of the memory size increase.

Could someone please correct me if this isn't the proper way of disposing objects?

```
while(Global.enemyB.Count > 0)
{
    var i = Global.enemyB[0];
    Global.form.Controls.Remove(Global.enemyB[0]);
    Global.enemyB[0] = null;
    Global.enemyB.RemoveAt(0);
    i.Dispose();
}
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: `for (int i = Global.enemyB.Count - 1; i >= 0;i--) { Global.enemyB[i].Dispose(); }`

Comment: dont name a var "i". It isn't even an index, it's a darn "first" -> my eyes are bleeding from that line. 

Why the nulling of enemyB[0] and which is referenced in reference "i" and then attempting to "Dispose" a nulled object... doesn't that cause an exception?

There isn't enough info here to help you, but likely the fact that the enemy list is connected to an object called "Global" is likely where your problem really is, if you actually have the problem you think you do.

Also, you very likely do not need to call the GC -> code smell.

Comment: When all Controls are disposed, clear the List. The Garbage Collector will do its job, when it *feels like* it. -- You need a lot of Labels to see a memory allocation increase. Unless your Labels contain graphic objects. If the graphics objects are assingned directly from the Project's Resources, then the memory usage will increase steadily (since each time you get an object from the Resources, you create a new copy): in this case, assign Resource objects to Fields (if you have just a few) or some other collection and dispose of these, too, when you're done.

Comment: @MortenBork: What do you mean by "a nulled object"? Changing the value of `Global.enemyB[0]` doesn't change the value of `i`...

Comment: @JonSkeet true, sorry! my bad, I don't know why I was thinking it was by value, and not reference.

Still, This is the most complicated way I have seen so far here on, simply "Global.enemyB.RemoveAt(0);"  would do.

Comment: @Jimi I dont have any graphics or images or anything assigned to these labels but I do add new labels to the list once I am done Disposing. I also tried getting rid of the variable i but  I still dont notice any memory decrease

Comment: What you need to do is to dispose of the objects you create. That's your job. After that, just `Clear()` the List. Memory allocation can increase (and, as mentioned, you really need a lot of Labels to notice it). The Garbage Collector will come by when it's necessary. Let it do its job. There's no real reason to expect an immediate memory usage decrease (if you don't have graphic objects) -- BTW, you didn't specify what kind of memory fluctuations you're experiencing. Keep the Diagnostic Tools open while debugging, maybe the memory usage increases because of something else.

Comment: hmmm is there anyways I can add a break point for the finalizer ? I obvious I know how to do it  for my own classes but I dont know how to do it for classes that are in DLL's

Comment: Im notice a memory increase around Half a MB every time I reload the labels , so  disposing + empty the list then  add new labels to the list and then putting them to the form. I am adding new labels to the list right after disposing the old ones so maybe that has something to do with it ??? I mean  its not really that I have a lot of labels on screen or anything but its a level editor so you need to switch between screens and such

Comment: I think the "Global" is your problem. 
Whenever you have a global variable, that isn't a configuration (and even then, it isn't great) you likely misunderstood how to build clean code for that object's behaviour or responsibilities. 

Having a global list of "Enemies" is likely an abstraction error. 
If you instead had to pass a parameter of enemies into methods that execute behaviour based on the parameter, you will have a lot more control over where and why the enemy list is used. You also have much better control over WHERE that parameter came from.

Comment: For example, which screens or objects can alter the enemy list? Which objects are going to get effected by this? Will they react to the change in time? etc. 

much better to do something like an observer pattern? 
Or maybe decorator/factory/strategy pattern, to handle when and how the enemy list is  influenced, so you do not have to rely on knowing all dependencies the global list has.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are usually inherits Dispose which can be used be free the objects. GC collect mainly will be used for free up memory related to heap objects.